# HTMLElementVariable.animate( ... ) alternative?

Tags: jquery

```
var $e = $('.class');
$e.animate({ something:1 });
```

Why can I not call any jquery function from a variable?

I'm trying to animate each element of the array individually. How can I animate the variables in $e according to their placement in the array. I know I can use this:

```
for (...) {
   $('.class')[i].animate();
}
```

But I'm guessing it will perform slower especially if there are a lot of elements. So are there any alternative methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You CAN call any jquery function from a variable. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The `.animate()` function is a jQuery function, so you can't call it on a DOM element (the `for` loop you mentioned in your question wouldn't actually work). You can, however, use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over a set of matched elements, and animate them individually:

```
$('.class').each(function(index, element) {
    $(element).animate(); // index is its position in the list
});
```